# Around advice behaving strange

Tags: java, spring, aop

I'm using XML based AOP in Spring, and i have the following pointcut:

```
<aop:aspect id=".." ref="..">
    <aop:pointcut id="interceptController" expression="execution(ModelAndView org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller+.handleRequest(HttpServletRequest, ..))" />
    <aop:around method="myAroundAdvice" pointcut-ref="interceptController" />
</aop:aspect>
```

My advice is the following:

```
public Object myAroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    if (someCondition) {
        Object test = jp.proceed();
        return test;
    }
    else {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:index.htm");
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that everything works fine if we get into the true clause of the if expression, however, if we get into the else clause, the program crashes with error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ... threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
```

So i put a breakpoint on the line `Object test = jp.proceed`, and i noticed that `jp.proceed();` returns the boolean `true`. Hence, in the else clause, when i return a new `ModelAndView` it crashes since it expected a boolean to be returned from the advice..

Why on earth is a boolean expected to be returned from this advice?? In the pointcut expression i specified that the return type of the method execution i am matching is `ModelAndView`, hence, `proceed()` as well as my advice should return a `ModelAndView`..

What am i missing here?

---

**UPDATE:** As pointed out, I tried printing the joinpoint. Therefore i printed the joinpoint as well as its target :

```
System.out.println("jp is : " + jp.toString());
System.out.println("target is : " + jp.getTarget().toString());
```

This prints the following when visiting a webpage :

```
jp is : org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint: execution(preHandle)
target is : my.packages.etc.LoginInterceptor@5b181df3

jp is : org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint: execution(postHandle)
target is : my.packages.etc.LoginInterceptor@5b181df3

jp is : org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint: execution(afterCompletion)
target is : my.packages.etc.LoginInterceptor@5b181df3
```

Note that `LoginInterceptor` extends the `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` class, so why is it matching with my pointcut? Because `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` is in `servlet.handler` while i match on `servlet.mvc.Controller+.handleRequest`.

---

Entire stracktrace:

```
18-nov-2016 14:52:26 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ... threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.preHandle(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:865)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:612)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: Did you check which method exactly was intercepted? And where exactly does the `ClassCastException` happen?

Comment: @PredragMaric It matches the controller's `handleRequest` method (which is an `AbstractController`). Hence my controller extends the `AbstractController` and implements the `handleRequestInternal` method. Hence, i'm matching with the `handleRequest` method which will call my `handleRequestInternal` method if i call `proceed()` and else i would want to return a new `ModelAndView` in order to redirect the user. Regarding the exception, it is thrown upon `return test;`. I will include the whole stacktrace in my post.

Answer (score 1):

I think your pointcut does not intercept what you think it does. For some reason it seems to intercept methods returning boolean values. Try printing `jp` on the console and see which method you have intercepted.

The pointcut as such looks basically okay, but one thing strikes me: `ModelAndView` is not a fully qualified class name. Maybe you want to change that.

Comment: You're right, i printed `jp.getTarget().toString()` which prints some class `LoginInterceptor` in my project. It seems that it intercepts the `preHandle` method of the `LoginInterceptor` class, which indeed returns a booleans. However, this `LoginInterceptor` class extends `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter` , so I don't get why this method is intercepted, since my pointcut should only intercept `HandleRequest` from the `servlet.mvc.Controller+` classes, while this method is in `servlet.handler`... Note that i changed `ModelAndView` to its fully qualified name.

Comment: I assume there is another pointcut associated with the same advice method because the one you show in your question would not intercept methods such as `preHandle`, `postHandle` or `afterCompletion`. Please check your aspect code as well as your configuration for other places referring to method `myAroundAdvice`.

Comment: Right, that's what i was thinking too, however, the original project did not integrated AOP. My job is to integrate AOP to do all kinds of stuff. I commented out all other pointcuts such that this really is the only pointcut, however, the problem persists. In order to be 100% sure, i changed the name of the advice, and in my xml file referred to that new name, however, the same behavior persists, hence, i am sure there is no other pointcut which accidentally pointed to the same advice. This is really weird.. I showed it to my teaching assistant too, and he was stumbled too.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, using annotation based AOP instead of XML based AOP, and rewriting the advises. Thanks for your help!